# How in jmeter we can handle encoded password which is generated in each and every run

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

How in jmeter we can handle encoded password which is generated in each and every run, I tried base64 encoded and each time the password is encrypted but the encoded password is not correct, It won't work for me. Please suggest me how to handle encoded password

Comment: If it is not working then probably the encoding algorithm is different. Are you facing this while authentication or you application is generating pwd in one request and then using it for other. HTTP authorization manager is used for handling authentication. In sampler there is an option to send the parameters using encoding. Can you give more information of what are you trying with some snapshots,if possible.

Comment: Application is generating and encoding the passowrd, I also tried checking the encode check-box.